# PHP - Replace JSON with the correct Unicode symbol

Tags: php, json, unicode, backslash, stripslashes

I have some JSON, that when decoded, I print out the result. Before the JSON is decoded, I use stripslashes() to remove extra slashes. The JSON contains website links, such as https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp and descriptions like `Hello World, I have u00249999999 dollars`

When I print out the JSON, I would like it to print out
`Hello World, I have $9999999 dollars`, but it prints out `Hello World, I have u00249999999 dollars`.

I assume that the `u0024` is not getting parsed because it has no backslash, though the thing is that the website links' forward slashes aren't removed through strip slashes, which is good - I think that the backslashes for the Unicode symbols are removed with stripslashes();

How do I get the PHP to automatically detect and parse the Unicode dollar sign? I would also like to apply this rule to every single Unicode symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PHP documentation on `stripslashes ()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php), it

> un-quotes a quoted string.

Which means, that it basically removes all backslashes, which are used for escaping characters (or Unicode sequences). When removing those, you basically have no chance to be completely sure that any sequence as `"u0024"` was meant to be a Unicode entity, your user could just have entered that.

Besides that, you will get some trouble when using `stripslashes ()` on a JSON value that contains escaped quotes. Consider this example:

```
{
  "key": "\"value\""
}
```

This will become invalid when using `stripslashes ()` because it will then look like this:

```
{
  "key": ""value""
}
```

Which is not parseable as it isn't a valid JSON object. When you don't use `stripslashes ()`, all escape sequences will be converted by the JSON parser and before outputting the (decoded) JSON object to the client, PHP will automatically decode (or "convert") the Unicode sequences your data may contain.

**Conclusion:** I'd suggest not to use `stripslashes ()` when dealing with JSON entities as it may break things (as seen in the previous example, but also in your problem).

Comment: This worked! I was not sure that it would work - as I just used stripslashes() to remove slashes that were automatically put there by the JSON encoder - I did not realize that the result objects could be parsed even though it looked messy when I used print_r() to print the data.

Thanks a lot! This really helped - Sorry for replying so late - I have exams on right now.

Answer (score 2):

The main question you have to understand, is why do you need to strip slashes?
And, if it is really necessary to strip slashes, how to manage the encoding? Probably it is a good idea to convert unicode symbols **before** to strip slashes, not after, using [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) .

Anyway, you can try fix the problem with this workaround:

```
$string = "Hello World, I have u00249999999 dollars";
$string = preg_replace( "/u([0-9A-F]{0,4})/", "&#x$1;", $string ); // recover "u" + 4 alnums
$string = html_entity_decode( $string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' ); // convert to utf-8
```

Comment: @MrLister you are right, I wrote the code quite fast just to indicate a possible way to face the problem, even if I don't agree with this kind of solutions.
But let me point out that the only problem in my code is the slash that must be converted to backslash: `$string = preg_replace( "/(u\d{4})/", "\\$1", $string );` obviously doubled `\\ ` to unescape it, then it will work with `mb_convert_encoding` for any char represented as \u+4digits as written in the comment to my code.
I've corrected my reply, now it is more pertinent than the other ones.

Comment: Thank for replying - I tried your suggestion, but it wouldn't work, as it would replace all the Unicode with a dollar sign. What I really wanted to do, was replace all the Unicode with the correct corresponding Unicode symbol. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @MrLister is always right (except when he writes my nickname). Anyway, here the final solution:
`$string = "Hello World, I have u00249999999 dollars";
$string = preg_replace( "/u([0-9A-F]{0,4})/", "&#x$1;", $string );
$string = html_entity_decode( $string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' );`. I update the answer.

Comment: @Kalamun OK. I removed my downvote (and my misspelled comments). But I still think the better answer is to not remove those backslashes from the source material in the first place.

Comment: @MrLister I agree, I removed the backslashes, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct: `u0024` is not getting parsed because it has no backslash. You can use regex to add backslash back after the conversion.

It looks like you have UTF-8 encoded strings internally, PHP outputs them properly, but your browser fails to auto-detect the encoding (it decides for ISO 8859-1 or some other encoding).

The best way is to tell the browser that UTF-8 is being used by sending the corresponding HTTP header:

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Then, you can leave the rest of your code as-is and don't have to html-encode entities or create other mess.

If you want, you can additionally declare the encoding in the generated HTML by using the `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> for HTML <=4.01
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

for HTML5
HTTP header has priority over the `<meta>` tag, but the latter may be useful if the HTML is saved to HD and then read locally.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I only just read your suggestion, but my problem is already solved. By the way, I did set the content type at the top of my document. Thanks for replying though! Have a great day!